# Is it possible to change default line spacing of the single text line?

Tags: android, mobile, textview

I faced with such issue. When I try to change line spacing on Android it doesn't work correctly in case of single text line. In case of two or more text lines it is working.

So, is it possible to make it with the single line?(

I've tried to use lineSpacingExtra, but it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Line spacing only exists if there's 2 or more lines-  its the spacing between them.  Maybe explain what you want, and what you're actually seeing?

Comment: @GabeSechan I have design, where single text line has additional line spacing instead of default. Default value is 14sp, but there is 16sp in design. So If I set the default value the screen will be different from the design in Figma.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add padding.  Since there's no second line, line spacing won't be applied.

Or if it's something that could be 1 or more lines and you need it applied in any case, maybe insert a \n to force a linebreak

Comment: I really don't get your question, lineSpacingExtra works with 2 lines or more, just a trick, add an empty line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.